# Overshadow data in aws glue studio

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I am constructing an ETL process in AWS Glue Studio where I get the data in a bucket s3 to remove some fields. After this process, I need to use a Custom Transformation to overshadow some data and then save it in a new s3 bucket.

When I use a Custom Transformation a block code is shown. So I need to create my code there.

My question is about it, how can I use it to construct my transformation, more specifically about input and output data, because I don't understand this process on AWS.

What I did at the moment was create the function that will manipulate this data. I get my fields using dfc['my_field'] and applied the transformation, but I don't understand what I need to return and how can I save it in an s3 bucket. below you can see my function.

```
def MyTransform (glueContext, dfc) -> DynamicFrameCollection:
import random
import hashlib
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, lit

df = dfc.select(list(dfc.keys())[0]).toDF()
print('printing key0')
df.show(3)
print('printed key0')
print('imprimindo o tipo de df')
print(type(df))

def encrypt_phone(df):
    '''
     Criptografa dados de telefone
    '''
    if df.withColumn('phone_main', df('phone_main')) is not None:
        hl = hashlib.sha256()
        hl.update(df.withColumn('phone_main', df('phone_main'))).encode().hexdigest()
        hl.update(df.withColumn('phone_alternative', df('phone_alternative'))).encode().hexdigest()
    return df

# Criar um UDF para encriptar os dados
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
encrypted_udf = udf(encrypt_phone)
print(encrypted_udf)

# Renomear coluna phone_main e phone_alternative
df.withColumnRenamed('phone_main', 'old_phone_main') \
                    .withColumnRenamed('phone_alternative', 'old_phone_alternative')

# Criar novas colunas para dados transformados
new_df = encrypt_phone(df)
encrypted = df.withColumn('phone_main', new_df('phone_main'))
encrypted = df.withColumn('phone_alternative',new_df('phone_alternative'))
print(encrypted)

# Remover campos sensíveis
encripted_df = df.drop('cpf_cnpj', 'name', 'nickname', 'old_phone_main', 'old_phone_alternative')
print(df_encrypted)

# Mascarar email
print(encripted_df.withColumn('email', df('email')))
if encripted_df.withColumn('email', df('email')) is not None:
    masked_df = encripted_df.withColumn('email', lit('****@*****'))
    
# Converter spark dataframe para Glue Dynamic Frame e retornar como um dataframe collection
df_overshadow = DynamicFrame.fromDF(masked_df, glueContext, "df_overshadow")

return (DynamicFrameCollection({"CustomTransform0": df_overshadow}, glueContext))
```

My process on glue studio to be structured like this image:

[image]

But, when I try to save an error is shown:

```
Parent node overshadow outputs a collection, but node Process-Client_PFS does not accept a collection.
```

I need to apply the transformation and save the data. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

`dfc` is a `DynamicFrameCollection`. You need to select your `DynamicFrame` from the collection for it to work. [From the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/ug/edit-jobs-transforms.html#transforms-custom):

> You must use a SelectFromCollection transform to choose a single DynamicFrame from the result of your Custom transform node before you can send the output to a target location.

This should return you first DynamicFrame:

```
dfc.select(list(dfc.keys())[0])
```

Comment: I change my code, but the error happens yet. The change that I did I put above in the question. If you can see and help me I appreciate it!

Comment: You still return a DynamicFrameCollection and not a DynamicFrame.

Comment: I did some correction in my code. Now the error shown is: 

```Error
TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable```

Comment: Can you maybe add the correction to the code?

Comment: I did it. The question here have the new code.

Comment: I am using glue studio and the logs do not show the line where the error happens!

Comment: You can go into the error logs of the job run and see where the error occurs.

Comment: But instead of accessing columns like this: `df('phone_main')`please try this: `df.phone_main`

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are passing list type to toDF() which might be causing the issue. If you want particular dynamicframe from the collection then you can access it by using name. First print the dfc.keys and then select the frame that you want to convert.

For example `df= dfc.select('<frame_name>').toDF()` and then use it in your code further.